# Related Rates: If the sun rises at a rate of...how fast is the shadow shortening?

Tags: calculus

A vertical pole is 30 ft high and is located 30 ft east of a tall building. If the sun is rising at a rate of 18 degrees per hour ($\frac{\pi}{10}$), how fast is the shadow of the pole on the building shortening when the elevation of the sun is $\frac{\pi}{6}$?

$$\frac{dA}{dt} = \frac{\pi}{10}$$

If s is the length of the shadow, then $\tan(A) =(30-s)/30$.

$$\tan(A) =\frac{(30-s)}{30}$$
$$30\tan(A)-30 =-s$$
$$s = 30 - 30\tan(A)$$
$$\frac{ds}{dt} = 0 - 30 \sec^2(A)\frac{\pi}{10}$$

So then $-30\sec^2(\frac{\pi}{6})(\frac{\pi}{10}) = -12.56637061$ which is not the answer :(

What'd I do wrong?

EDIT:
I forgot to divide by $\pi$ and negate. Sorry!

Comment: You defined $ds/dt$ to be positive in the $+y$ direction, and the shadow is shortening which is why you get a negative answer. But the question asks how fast the shadow is shortening, which is asking for the speed in the $-y$ direction. Have you tried negating your answer?

Comment: The answer is 4$\pi$ft/hr, so even if I negate it, it would still be wrong. Oh wait, if I divide by -$\pi$ it's 4... Hehe, thanks!

Comment: $4\pi = 12.56637$

Comment: ... approximately :-)

Comment: By the way, this problem is flawed in multiple ways. First, the relative motion of the sun on the celestial sphere is only $15^\circ$ per hour, so it is impossible for it to rise at a rate of $18^\circ$ per hour. Second, the sun does not rise "straight up" except under rare circumstances; it generally has some "sideways" apparent motion as well, so the shadow moves along the wall and the distance from the pole to the shadow is changing. Hence the intended method of solution is invalid for almost any real-life case. But that is not your fault; it is the fault of whoever wrote this exercise.

Comment: Also, $30\sec^2\left(\frac{\pi}{6}\right)\left(\frac{\pi}{10}\right) = 30\left(\frac{4}{3}\right)\left(\frac{\pi}{10}\right) = \frac{30 \cdot4\cdot\pi}{3\cdot10}$, so you just have to cancel out 30 above and below. Or if you use a calculator, just multiply all the factors _except_ the factor of $\pi$ (which you can do because $\left(\frac{\pi}{10}\right) = \left(\frac{1}{10}\right)\pi$).